# Using the covariant derivative for a Riemannian Metric for $H^1([0,1]; S^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, global-analysis

I am currently researching gradient flows on Riemannian Hilbert manifolds and in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214433845), Trombe considers the Hilbert space $((H^1([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^3), \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{H})$ with inner product $\langle u,v\rangle_H := \langle u,v\rangle_{L^2} + \langle u', v'\rangle_{L^2}$ as a Hilbert manifold and I want to know why for $p \in H(I;S^2)$ the dot product he uses

$$ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: T_pH(I;S^2) \times T_pH(I;S^2), (u,v) \mapsto \langle \frac{Du}{\partial t}, \frac{Dv}{\partial t} \rangle $$

defines a Riemannian metric on $H(I;S^2$). I know that I may of course use the by the identity embedding $i: H(I;S^2) \hookrightarrow H(I;\mathbb{R}^3)$ induced pullback metric

$$g_{H(I;S^2)_p} (u,v)(p) := \langle di_p(u), di_p(v) \rangle_{T_{i(p)}H \simeq H} = \langle u, v \rangle_H$$ 
for $u,v \in T_w H(I;S^2)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which properties do you need to check for this to be a Riemannien metric? Where do you have trouble?

Comment: Smoothness wrt. to $p$: For the sphere I can write $\frac{Du}{\partial t}(t) = u'(t) - \langle u'(t), p(t) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^3}p(t)$ but I was thinking that there might be a more natural way than explicitly calculating the differential.